# Getting "error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0." when calling a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Getting an error

> error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

when the class instance is called. How can I fix this?

```
class ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private errorService: BackendErrorsService) {}
    getError() {
        console.log('error called');
    }
}

const instance = new ErrorHandler().getError();
```

Comment: Your constructor takes `errorService` but when you call `new ErrorHandler()` you aren't supplying it.

Comment: Is it mean that, I need to pass `BackendErrorsService` each time I call?

Comment: You haven't said it's an optional argument, so TS expects it there every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular automatically resolve dependencies of components and services. However, when you call your class
like that:

```
const instance = new ErrorHandler().getError();
```

Then you need to supply a dependency `BackendErrorsService`. Something like that:

```
let backendErrorsService = new BackendErrorsService();
const instance = new ErrorHandler(backendErrorsService ).getError();
```